# Webpack - Keep the same folder structure for output (typescript + asp.net-core-2.0)

Tags: typescript, webpack, asp.net-core-2.0, babeljs, .net-core-2.0

Any help is highly appreciated.

Following structure is in my asp.net core 2.0 app.

```
project
├───Controller
│   └───HomeController.cs
├───Scripts
│   ├───FolderA
│   │   ├───A1.ts
│   │   ├───A2.ts
│   │   └───A3.ts
│   ├───FolderB
│   │   │───FolderB1
│   │   │   └───B11.ts
│   │   └───FolderB2
│   │       ├───B21.ts
│   │       └───B22.ts
│   ├───FolderC
│   │   ├───C1.ts
│   │   └───C3.ts
│   └───outside.ts
├───Views
│   ├───Home
│   │   └───Index.cshtml
│   └───Shared
│       └───Layout.cshtml
└───wwwroot
│   └───Output
│       └───[Same structure like /Scripts]
├───project.csproj
├───Program.cs
├───StartUp.cs
├───package.json
├───tsconfig.json
├───webpack.config.json
```

Contents inside Scripts folder are all typescripts files


**1. Is there a way to pass all typescript files to webpack entry


2. Can we have same folder structure like Scripts/TypeScripts (.ts files) inside wwwroot/Output (.js files) after webpack is executed**

Below is my code for webpack.config.json

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
**// 1. Need something like wildcard to grab everything inside this TypeScripts folder**
        A1: './Scripts/TypeScripts/FolderA/A.ts',
        B11: './Scripts/TypeScripts/FolderB/FolderB1/B11.ts',
        B21: './Scripts/TypeScripts/FolderB/FolderB2/B21.ts',
        B22: './Scripts/TypeScripts/FolderB/FolderB2/B22.ts',
        C1: './Scripts/TypeScripts/FolderC/C1.ts',
        outside: './Scripts/TypeScripts/outside.ts'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: [["env"]]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    output: {
**// 2. Need a way to keep same structure in wwwroot/Output/**
        // The format for the outputted files
        filename: '[name].js',
        // Put the files in "wwwroot/Output/"
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/Output/')
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you actually using webpack for bundling? It seems you might want to use `tsc` directly to just transpile the TypeScript, but not bundle it. Adding each file as a webpack entry is a bit counter-intuitive to what it does.